# Vim plugin only works when file is provided as arg to launch command

Tags: java, vim, editor

I am using the plugin [java_getset.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=490). The issue is that the plugin's commands are only available when I launch vim with the file as an argument.

```
user@machine~: vim myfile.java
```

If launch vim and use command-t or NerdTree to open the file in a buffer the plugin's commands are not accessible. All the filetype detection stuff is configured and working(I have syntax highlighting and indentation). The plugin source appears to be written to the letter according the the vim docs for a filetype plugin. Can anyone help me understand what changes a can make so that I can use this plugin in conjunction with Command-t?

Comment: no I abandoned the plugin. lornix's solution didn't help

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the source code, it seems like the ftplugin isn't triggered if you re-use the current buffer.   I don't use command-t (nor this plugin), but it MIGHT work if you were to

```
:bdel
```

and try loading your file.

Try loading the file directly yourself:

```
:edit myfile.java
```

--or--

```
:edit! myfile.java
```

Does that work?